# Postfix lost connection after AUTH

Tags: php, postfix

Postfix mailserver installed on CentOS 7.3, Nginx php-fpm. Sending mail works from console but using php mail function, it doesn't work. **If it is needed I can add php.ini.**

I am getting following error from log. I've appended postfix config as well could anyone guess what's possibly wrong.

## error log

```
connect from server1.domain.com[1.1.1.1]
lost connection after AUTH from server1.domain.com[1.1.1.1]
disconnect from from server1.domain.com[1.1.1.1]
```

## postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd 
$daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = 1.1.1.1, 127.0.0.1
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = server1.domain.com
mynetworks = 1.1.1.1
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**php-fpm conf**

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = unlimited

[www]
user = nobody
group = nobody
listen.mode = 777
listen = '/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock'

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 100
pm.max_spare_servers = 100
pm.max_requests = 1000
request_terminate_timeout = 152
catch_workers_output = no

php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix -t -i
```

Comment: Are you trying php-mail with authentication? If so have you installed sasl to work with postfix? Since your php-mail function resides in the same server you can use php-mail without authentication but I would recommend installing sasl.

Comment: @eranga thanks, sasl wasn't installed, after installing script confirms email is sent but it's not received at receiving end?

Comment: Send a new email and post the last 10 lines of the maillog